# Best practice for blank top level menu item?

Tags: menus

I create a LOT of WP sites and therefore tons of menus.  A lot of times there is no sensible page for a top level menu item.  For instance I was creating a site with internal learning.  The top level menu item just goes to homepage.  Is this a good practice if there is no good page for them to go to or would it be better to go no where?

Comment: Might this be a better fit for [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)? I don't see how this wouldn't equally apply to non-WP navigation menus...

Comment: @JohannesPille - Well it would be a good question there too but I am looking for a solution that I would be able to implement in WP and share with clients.

Comment: This certainly doesn't answer your question but I most often see the empty anchor # used for an empty parent of a menu.  `<a href="#">` for example.  This keeps the user on the same page w/o a reload